# Extracting coefficients from a regression 1 model with 1 predictor

Tags: r, regression

I currently have the following regression model:

```
> print(summary(step1))

Call:
lm(formula = model1, data = newdat1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.53654 -0.02423 -0.02423 -0.02423  1.71962 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.3962     0.0532   7.446 2.76e-12 ***
i2            0.6281     0.0339  18.528  < 2e-16 ***
```

I would like just the following returned as a data frame:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
i2            0.6281     0.0339  18.528  < 2e-16
```

I currently have the following code:

```
> results1<-as.data.frame(summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,drop=FALSE])
```

Which yields:

```
> results1
  summary(step1)$coefficients[-1, drop = FALSE]
1                                  6.280769e-01
2                                  5.320108e-02
3                                  3.389873e-02
4                                  7.446350e+00
5                                  1.852804e+01
6                                  2.764836e-12
7                                  2.339089e-45
```

Thus is not what I want; however, it does work when there's more than 1 predictor.

Comment: You are missing a comma, try `summary(step1)$coefficients[-1,,drop=FALSE]` You can also use the `coef` function btw.

Comment: That worked perfectly, but how would I use the coef function?

Comment: See Bens answer, I'd go with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice if you gave a reproducible example.  I think you're looking for

```
cc <- coef(summary(step1))[2,,drop=FALSE]
as.data.frame(cc)
```

Using accessors such as `coef(summary(.))` rather than `summary(.)$coefficients` is both prettier and more robust (there is no guarantee that the internal structure of `summary()` will stay the same -- although admittedly it's unlikely that this basic a part of R will change any time soon, especially as many users probably *have* used constructions like `$coefficients`).

Indexing the row by name, i.e.

```
coef(summary(step1))["i2",,drop=FALSE]
```

would probably be even better.

Comment: coef function worked fine, but I cannot specific rows or items by name as this needs to be automated and these names will change frequently.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

`summary(step1)$coefficients` is a matrix. When you take out the first element with `[-1, drop=FALSE]` it is converted to a vector, which is why you get 7 numbers instead of the row you want.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- rnorm(100)
> y <- -1 + 0.2*x + rnorm(100)
> step1 <- lm(y ~ x)
> class(summary(step1)$coefficients)
[1] "matrix"
> class(summary(step1)$coefficients[-1, drop=FALSE])
[1] "numeric"
```

The solution is to change the subsetting with `[` so that you specify you wan to keep all columns (see ?`[`):

```
> summary(step1)$coefficients[-1, , drop=FALSE]
   Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
 x 0.1475284  0.1068786 1.380336 0.1706238
```

Comment: Or to use the accessor function `coef()` as Ben points out in his answer.

Comment: Didn't see your comment when I started writing an answer, my bad.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes I realize that please submit your initial comment as the answer.  To everybody else thank you for the additional info.